# IP Encryptor and Firewall

Tags: firewalls, ipsec

Firewalls implement IPsec VPN and perform packet filtering. IP Encryptor, on the other hand implements IPsec VPN and achieve security goals (confidentiality, integrity and authentication).
What are the advantages of IP Encryptor over Firewall?

Comment: This really sounds like a homework question. Is it?

Comment: It's a research problem I came across today :)

Comment: And you know what an IP Encryptor is, how it was used, and what its features were?

Comment: Yes I have studied IP encryptor. It is a standalone device that contains it's own processor and memory. It is connected to a computer. It encrypts the traffic and forwards the traffic on the internet through its port.